# Can session fixation attack in Laravel application be protected by session_regenerate?

Tags: php, laravel, security, session

I'm using session in Laravel app which has login function.

Session is stored in DB.

My app session generates session Name "laravel_session".

Maybe, it is default Name.(I checked it in chrome debugger.)

I thought it can cause session fixation.
So, I use `session->regenerate()` after Login process.
However, it generate "laravel_session" again. Is it working?
I checked sessions table after `session->regenerate()` and I found column "id" is changed.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of how session fixation works. It's not the cookie name, it's the session ID, which (as you've noticed) is correctly changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a huge difference between `session_name()` (which names the cookie) and `session_id()` (which should be a random, unpredictable value).

Your session name is public knowledge. It's the session ID that needs to be secret.

(Think of it as a `key => value` pair.)

Anyway, the point of `session_regenerate_id(true);` and the `use_strict_mode` configuration directive is to mitigate session fixation issues. You should always regenerate session IDs when the user changes their level of privilege (logging in, logging out, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Laravel already contains built-in protections against sesssion fixation, and a built-in function for you to do it yourself:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session

> Laravel automatically regenerates the session ID during authentication if you are using the built-in LoginController; however, if you need to manually regenerate the session ID, you may use the regenerate method.
>
> ```
> $request->session()->regenerate();
> ```